# How to get key Value from post webservice API and fetch that to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I got data from API in this format but the problem is that I want to get all questions and answers from the API but whenever I try to get the value by using the key value it returns nil value and application crashes

this is my api data looks like after getting into a dictionary
[image: this is what my data looks like I want to show the "Options" key data into my tableView]

[image]

here's my code for getting data from API

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header ).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:

              print(response)

            if let result = response.result.value {

                print(result)

                let responseDict = result as! [String : Any]

                print(responseDict)


              let data = responseDict["Result"] as! [Any] 

                print(data)
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if let res = responseDict["Result"] as? [[String:Any]]  {

    for item in res {

          if let ques = item["Question"] as? String  {

             print(ques)

          }

          if let op = item["Options"] as? [[String:Any]]  {

             print(op)

          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got one last question how to show the question in tableView Cell?

Comment: look to this this http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/